# Cache coherence on atomic variable

Tags: c++11, atomic

```
std::atomic_bool flag{false};
int data{0};

void sendRequest()
{
    // send request over network
}

bool replyReceived()
{
    // return true when reply is received over the network, false otherwise
}

void threadA()
{
    data = 123;
    flag.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst);  // (1)
    sendRequest();
}

void threadB()
{
    while (!replyReceived())
    {
    }
    if (flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire))  // (2)
    {
        // processing on data (3)
    }
}
```

In the above listing, `threadA()` and `threadB()` are run by different threads.  `threadA()` sends a network request whereas `threadB()` receives the reply of the request.  `flag` is an atomic variable to ensure that new value of `data` is observed in (3).  My question is should (2) always evaluate to true?  Is it possible for it to be false even though (1) must have been executed before (2) in real time?  The platform is x86.

Comment: *"should (2) always evaluate to true?"* Not in the code as shown. You seem to imply some kind of synchronization between `sendRequest` and `replyReceived`, but its nature is not clear from the question. If you somehow know that `sendRequest` call must *happen-before* `replyReceived` can return `true`, then you don't need `flag` in the first place.

Comment: @Igor: Yes, I'm thinking the same.  Rather than using a `while` loop to check the condition at (2), is there any simple way to check the condition only once?  I'm thinking changing (2) to std::memory_order_seq_cst does not help.

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)